# Is it normal to have less partition than broker count kafka configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs

Currently I have 3 brokers and a topic with 1 partition

My Kafdrop image can be seen below

[image]

[image]

I am facing the issue wheere consumer is complaining that

```
Error: The client consumer subscribed to the topic (my-topic) whcih is not assigned to any partitions.
```

I think that the consumer is being connected to a Broker that does not "control" the partition. But I do not know much about kafka and why the consumer will not be subscribing to the correct broker?

So my question is:

1/ Is it normal to have less partition than broker count

2/ If it is, should the consumer face the problem I faced or not and how to fix it?

UPDATE 1:
[Consumer setup](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/kafka) using **NEST.js**
[image]

and

```
streamClient.subscribeToResponseOf(...);
```

Comment: 1) yeah it's okay, sometimes you need for example order in a topic, therefore, you need just 1 partition regardless of how many brokers your cluster has 2) Can you please add consumer configs here.

Comment: Thanks @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ I made some update. I am using NEST.JS as a wrapper for Kafka

Comment: The downside of having only one partition is that only one consumer from a given group can work on that topic at a given time. So you can't for example spawn 3 consumers and expect them to share the consumption workload.
(# of  parallel consumers in a group) === (# of partitions)